# move the array elements to their next position if one element inserted at some index position

Tags: java

Below is my input array

```
int[] myarray= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int inputNo=10;   // value to be inserted

int index=3;       // position to be inserted
```

Then output should,

```
{1,2,3,10,4,5,6,7}
```

Comment: you have to make a new array.

Comment: did you even write any code ?

Comment: how to create dynamically based on index position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] insertedArray = new int[myarray.length+1];
System.arrayCopy( myarray, 0, insertedArray, 0, index );
System.arrayCopy( myarray, index, insertedArray, index+1, myarray.length-index);
insertedArray[index] = inputNo;
```

And maybe, depending on the context ...

```
myarray = insertedArray
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you consider it the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a LinkedList (in order to keep the order) instead of an array.

LinkedList have a method to put data on a specific index.

```
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(index, element);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`length of an array is immutable`**. We cannot change the size of an array once we have created it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(2);
        myList.add(3);
        myList.add(4);
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(6);
        myList.add(7);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()));
        myList.add(3, 10);// index 3, value 10
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()));
    }
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```